# Prevent the cell from expanding to the size of cell contents in a Google Spreadsheet every time I open it?

Tags: google-sheets

I know how to "Wrap text" to make this happen, but my issue is I am having to do this EVERY time I open a spreadsheet in Google Docs. It is a quick couple of clicks, but it adds up. Is there a way to make 'set wrapping off' as the default?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The default wrap setting in new Google Sheets appear to be the opposite of that in the previous version. Switch to new Google Sheets.